# Intellij output too much information

Tags: java, intellij-idea, output

Wondering if there is anyway I can clean the output of intellij when executing a java app with arguments. I require to see only the arguments and all the information before the app name have no use for me and hoping I can turn them off for now.

e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7538 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\asd\IdeaProjects\Assignment1\out\production\Assignment1;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 12.0\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Problem2 25 -5 10 5frf
```

As you can see, the arguments are the last 4 words in this. I would just simply like to see the app.java arg1 arg2 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite that I don't think you can change this, what about this simple Java solution:

```
class Something{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for (String arg : args){
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
        System.out.println("--------");
    }

}
```

Seems I'm right. Here is the documentation for the ["Run"-View](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-tool-window.html). It doesn't include any information on doing something like this.

---

An idea to not forget to remove this in final releases would be to add a `//TODO Remove this`. IntelliJ can list all ToDo's in a list and before you ship it out you just look over all todos and remove it.

Another idea would be emulating a `#define` from C by simply having a `public static final boolean RELEASED` which you set to `true` when you release the code. You can check for that flag and modern Java compilers will most likely optimize the output-block away.

Comment: Already thought about that, The issue was I would require to add that too many apps and I will forget about removing it for the final which is a small bother.

Comment: @RezaM. I added some ideas about that.